# Managing user errors on Self-Register though communities

Tags: community, lightning-community

External customers are registered via Self Registered page. I want to configure validation errors so that users have more understanding about mistakes they do on login page such as entering existing userID . so we want to custmise the user friendly erorr massage such as "User ID already exist, please enter another user ID"

User always get "Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted"

I already check in "LightningSelfRegisterController" to customize error massage, But there is no mention to error messages in the controller. If I know the page or controller these messages are generated I can customise them.

Comment: I had good look on the all lightning component on our environment which control login. But I couldn't find any

Comment: your community is most likely using the default one, you will have to create your own component for what you want

Comment: Last I knew, providing specific error messages for login/registration forms was not considered best practice because doing so can leak information to attackers (after confirming a target, likely privileged, login, all we have to do is probably run through the 100 most used passwords list). Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I customized the LightningselfRegisterController to handle user errors and replaced the page on registration area of the community login. But user error message hasn't been changed